Performance issues with raster thread and AndroidContextGL::SwapBuffers
When I run my flutter app in profile mode to check performance, I encounter huge raster jank, with frames taking up to 32ms to build. When I look at the detail of this issue, I find that it's because the AndroidContextGL::SwapBuffers process is taking this entire time. Unfortunately it's not entirely clear to me what this does, apparently its simply a process that submits the frame to the GPU but I don't know what I can do to make it work better.
full profile view,
details of Timeline Events
I've tried disabling parts of my app to see if this would prevent this from happing but even when I literally disabled my entire app and only showcased a nearly blank page the frame still wouldn't go under 17ms.
Other than that I don't have a clue of what I can do. Maybe its some kind of problem with my gpu and not the app itself, or maybe it has to do with my emulator.
